# Unable to set checkpoint in partition

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I am trying to use this sample (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send) but I am not able to read unread data only. One more thing I am getting two different error

1) connect ETIMEDOUT 40.112.242.0:5671

2) lease lost while updating checkpoint

In the node js sample, I am not able to set checkpoints. I have tried Azure/azure-sdk-for-js as well. But it is showing the same error listed above.

When I have also run .netcore sample then they are working fine so I am not getting why node js sample is not working fine?

Can you please guide me on how can fix this issue to read-only unread and new data?

Comment: Can you solve your issue now?

Answer (score 0):

For node.js, please use the code below to set checkpoint, it works well at my side:

```
const { EventProcessorHost, delay } = require("@azure/event-processor-host");

//your eventhub name
const path = "myeventhub"; 

//your azure storage connection string
const storageCS = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

//your eventhub namespace connectionstring 
const ehCS = "Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxx"

//your blob storage container name
const storageContainerName = "test6";

async function main() {
  // Create the Event Processo Host
  const eph = EventProcessorHost.createFromConnectionString(
    EventProcessorHost.createHostName("my-host"),
    storageCS,
    storageContainerName,
    ehCS,
    {
      eventHubPath: path
    }

  );
  let count = 0;
  // Message event handler
  const onMessage = async (context/*PartitionContext*/, data /*EventData*/) => {
    console.log(">>>>> Rx message from '%s': '%s'", context.partitionId, data.body);
    count++;

    return await context.checkpoint();
  };
  // Error event handler
  const onError = (error) => {
    console.log(">>>>> Received Error: %O", error);
  };
  // start the EPH
  await eph.start(onMessage, onError);
  // After some time let' say 2 minutes
  await delay(120000);
  // This will stop the EPH.
  await eph.stop();
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

And I can see the checkpoint is set correctly in blob container:

[image]

Comment: If it works for you, please help mark it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am able to set the checkpoint but they are reading all data not the new or unread data.
Earlier my sample is set the checkpoint but not reading new data so can you please help me to read new data only.

Comment: @user3400763, the purpose of checkpoint is to read the unread data. And if you set checkpoint at the first time, then it will read all data. And next time, when new data comes in, it will only read the new data. Is it clear for you :)

Comment: I am also facing a few issues like

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An error occurred while getting lease for partitionId '17':Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: @user3400763, do you follow my code exactly? and install the latest version package of azure eventhub? can you see the checkpoint are set in blob storage?

Comment: @user3400763, it works fine at my side. And for testing purpose, can you create a new eventhub and then run the code?